# Can Beautiful Soup parse hidden attributes?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I used Beautiful Soup in python to parse a page that displays all my facebook friends.Here's my code:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 r=requests.get("https://www.facebook.com/xxx.xxx/friendspnref=lhc")
 soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

 for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    print link.get('href')
```

The thing is it displays a lot of links but none of them are links to my friends' profiles,which are displayed normally on the webpage.
On doing Inspect element I fount this

```
 <div class="hidden_elem"><code id="u_0_2m"><!--
```

The code continues,and the links to their profiles are commented within an li tag in the div tag.
Two questions mainly:

(1.)What does this mean and why can't Beautiful Soup read them?

(2.)Is there a way to read them?

I really don't plan to achieve anything by this ,just curious.

Comment: if you check the html of that hidden elem it seems like a mission impossible to parse that data, however, it seems like facebook has some kind of API, [here](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)

Comment: This is not an answer to your problem but it's against facebook's policy to scrape pages

Comment: Never scraped fb but...before you scrape any website, check their robot.txt file. It will contain a 'disallow' section and you should at the very least read it before you scrape. Also, it may be the case that some content is hidden/masked by js and frames - if so, it is kind of an indicative 'do not scrape'. Good luck!